# Dequeue Non_Persistent message from AQ Queue using JMS

Tags: java, oracle, queue, jms, buffered

I would like to dequeue a non persistent (=buffered) JMS Message from an Oracle AQ queue.

In PL/SQL everything is fine and works, if I set

```
L_DequeueOptions.VISIBILITY    := DBMS_AQ.IMMEDIATE;
L_DequeueOptions.DELIVERY_MODE := DBMS_AQ.BUFFERED;
```

on the dequeuer.

The enqueuer options are set accordingly to IMMEDIATE and BUFFERED.

Nevertheless in Java Code I try to receive the message using JMS with a javax.jms.QueueReceiver using

```
QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue, "JMSDeliveryMode = 'PERSISTENT' or JMSDeliveryMode = 'NON_PERSISTENT'");
// and later on:
Message m = receiver.receive(conf.dequeueTimeout);
```

I'm not running in a transaction on the dequeuer/receiver side.
How can I set the "visibility" in JMS?
Any ideas why I do not receive the messages?

What am I missing?

Payload is sys.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE, non compressed or the like.

btw: the dequeuing application is working using persistent messages...

**Update:** the code does not work for persistent messages also, if I use the MessageSelector. Without message selector and persistent messages it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out, how to manage this.
Directly on JMS there is no way to dequeue non-persistent messages. I doubt that non-persistent dequeuing is part of the standard.

The only way is to cast the QueueReceiver to an `oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer` and then call

```
      receiver.bufferReceive(timeout);
```

instead of

```
      receiver.receive(timeout);
```

Only debugging in Oracle JMS code brought us to this solution.
There is poor documentation on this on the web.

Btw: the message selector led me in the complete wrong direction.

Comment: What standard are you talking about with regards to dequeuing non-persistent messages?

Comment: I'm talking about JMS Standard, which defines a JMSDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT (and I thought that it also should be possible to dequeue non persistent messages using JMS).

Comment: According to the JMS specification it's certainly possible to dequeue/consume non-persistent messages. If OracleAQ doesn't support this functionality then it isn't fully compliant with the JMS spec.

Answer (score 1):

The JMS specification (JSR 914) defines two delivery modes: `PERSISTENT` and `NON_PERSISTENT`. Regarding Oracle these modes are `PERSISTENT` and `BUFFERED`.

However, it seems Oracles JMS implementation does only receives the `PERSISTENT` ones per default.

The message selector itself is checked by Oracle implementation, but seems not to have a effect on the delivery mode.

As stated by yourself, the `QueueReceiver` can be casted to a `AQjmsConsumer` to handle buffered messages.

```
AQjmsConsumer consumer = (AQjmsConsumer)session.createReceiver(queue);
consumer.bufferReceive(dequeueTimeout);
```

The same applies when sending buffered messages. Here the `QueueSender` must be casted to a `AQjmsProducer` to have a method for buffered messages at hand:

```
AQjmsProducer producer = (AQjmsProducer)session.createProducer(queue);
producer.bufferSend(queue, msg, priority, timeToLive);
```